# Properly escaping shell arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

Here is the code:

```
desc "Find 301 errors on production servers"
task :find301 do
  command = "grep 'HTTP/1.1\" 301' /var/log/httpd/*ssl-access.log | grep -v 'gclid' | awk '{print \$7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"

  production_servers.each do |server|
    sh "ssh root@#{server} #{command}"
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to escape the shell command, preferably in a format that allows `sh "ssh root@#{server} #{command}"` to be used with arbitrary `command`s?

Comment: Don't build command lines with string operations, use the multi-argument form of [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) or [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) and bypass the shell completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `require 'shellwords'` and `Shellwords.escape`
You can find more info on these in "[shellescape](http://apidock.com/ruby/Shellwords/shellescape)" and "[Shellwords](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html)"

Comment: shellwords monkey patches String, which I like: `"foo bar".shellescape == "foo\\ bar"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%q` and `%Q` versions, but you still need to specify a delimiter.

```
%Q|these don't need to be escaped /\"'"'{}[]-_+=()!@#$%^&*`~;:<>.,|
```